# kinect + ubuntu 12.04 + fuerte

Tags: kinect, ros-fuerte, ubuntu, ubuntu-precise

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recently installed ubuntu 12.04 and fuerte on it, I am using openni launch package
but it's giving me a lot of errors also there is no topic named /camera/depth/points because of which rviz is giving error when i am subscribing to pointCloud2.
also it seems that the IR projector of the kinect is not working, I tried this with other kinect but the same problem occurs.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51704/kinect-+-ubuntu-12.04-+-fuerte/) by [akhil](https://answers.ros.org/users/2787/akhil/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2013-01-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-01-08**:
Please read the [Support Guidelines](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Support) and add relevant information to your question: What exact steps (commands) reproduce your problem? What are the exact errors (copy&paste)?

**Comment by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) on 2013-01-08**:
Search through previous answers and you will find a lot of information. Are you by any chance using USB3.0 ports? There have been reports of problems with that. You might also have to use a patched version of OpenNI... I needed to do that on my 64 bit Ubuntu 12.04.

**Comment by [akhil](https://answers.ros.org/users/2787/akhil/) on 2013-01-09**:
thanks for your reply, I am not using usb3.0 I read those questions and was able to fix those errors but still im not getting /camera/depth/points as one of the topics when I run openni_launch .

**Comment by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) on 2013-01-10**:
Also, you should probably post your console output when you run the openni launch file and when you run lsusb (to see if your hardware is detected by the OS).

**Comment by [akhil](https://answers.ros.org/users/2787/akhil/) on 2013-01-15**:
thanks georgebrindeiro it solved my problem ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you checked out the verified answer to this question? It helped me when I had issues in ROS Fuerte+Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit: http://answers.ros.org/question/33622/openni_launch-not-working-in-fuerte-ubuntu-precise-1204/

---

Originally posted by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) with karma: 1264 on 2013-01-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1